# Specifying client credentials when running a WCF Service from WCF Test Client

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication

I have a WCF Service that I used to running from WCF Test Client. Now I have added custom authentication with username and password to my service and wanted to know how would I pass username and password? Is that still possible to specify client credentials via WCF Test Client?

Here are my custom validator and user account classes:

```
public class CustomUserValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (null == userName || null == password)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        UserAccountModel uam = new UserAccountModel();

        if(uam.Login(userName, password))
            return;
        throw new SecurityTokenException("User invalid.");

    }
}



public class UserAccountModel
{

    private List<UserAccount> listUserAccounts = new List<UserAccount>();

    public UserAccountModel()
    {
        using (UserAccountContext ctx = new UserAccountContext())
        {
            listUserAccounts = ctx.UserAccounts.ToList();
        }
    }

    public bool Login(string _usrname, string _pwd)
    {
        return listUserAccounts.Count(lua => lua.Username.Equals(_usrname) && lua.Pwd.Equals(_pwd)) > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the clientCredentials endpoint behavior to specify client credentials, such as certificates. You have to create a custom extension. But have you considered to temporary turn off authentication? After all, the test client is used for testing purpose only.

Comment: why would I turn off authentication?